# Spree backend + Core rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I'm trying to install spree on my rails-4 application with only backend and api stuff. I've found on the web how to install spree for a rails4 application and I also found how to install only backend and api stuff. The problem is folowing, to install rails-4 I need to set it in branch :

gem 'spree', github: 'spree/spree', branch: 'rails4'

But if I want to use only spree's backend and api, I would usually specify them manually in gemfile :

gem 'spree_backend'
gem 'spree_api'

But since there is not specific git repo for them (they are all subfolders) I can't find out how to specify a subfolder in github in a specific branch.

Did I miss something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not missing something.  The project in to separate gems when it is released.  Spree doesn't have a subtree split of the subdirectories, so if you want to pull it in from git you'll have to do some work, or import the whole project.

Your best bet may be to try:

```
gem 'spree', github: 'spree/spree', branch: 'rails4', require: false
```

This will install the gem and maintain the dependencies, but not require anything.  You can then manually require the sections that you want in an initializer.

Comment: Thanks it did the trick! Hopefully they release the gems at rubygems soon enough